# Cell based NSTableView – Trying to allow cell editing

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have a cell based NSTableView.
Two columns are editable.

I made the two columns editable and also made their TextCells editable, and set their action to be "Sent on End Editing."

I then tried to connect the TextCells to @IBAction functions in my ViewController.

The cells appear to be editable when I run my code but changes that I make aren't reflected in the cells when I hit enter and my IBAction isn't being triggered.

What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Here is where I'm implementing my TableView functions, which do display the expected values:

```
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        var numRows : Int = 0
        if tableView.identifier?.rawValue == "xml" {
            numRows = xmls.count
        }
        return numRows
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        var cell : String = ""
        if tableView.identifier?.rawValue == "xml" {
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "xml" {
                cell = xmls[row].lastPathComponent
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "pn" {
                cell = pn[row]
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "init" {
                cell = init[row]
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "dn" {
                cell = dn[row]
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

And here I was trying to make an action that fires when one of the editable cells was edited, however it is not getting triggered:

```
@IBAction func deviceNumberCellWasEdited(_ sender: Any) {
    print("cell was edited")
}
```

(In my storyboard I have set the properties of the cell to Behavior: Editable and Action: Sent on End Editing.)

[image]

Here is the corrected code, with tableView:setObject:forTableColumn:row: implemented.

```
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        var numRows : Int = 0
        if tableView.identifier?.rawValue == "xml" {
            numRows = xmls.count
        }
        return numRows
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        var cell : String = ""
        if tableView.identifier?.rawValue == "xml" {
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "xml" {
                cell = xmls[row].lastPathComponent
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "pn" {
                cell = pn[row]
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "init" {
                cell = init[row]
            }
            if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "dn" {
                cell = dn[row]
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: Any?, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {
        if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "dn" {
            dn[row] = object as! String
        }
        if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "init" {
            init[row] = object as! String
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hint: `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`

Comment: @ElTomato, my ViewController does implement tableView:objectValue:forTableComumn:row:, and all of the column cells display the expected values. However when I double click on one of the editable cells and modify the value in that cell – then hit enter – the value doesn't change. I thought I would be a able to create an action from that cell that was triggered when a cell was edited.

Comment: I can't help you.  You are not showing a single line of code.  That's the violation of a rule here.

Comment: There is code in my post above. Is it not visible?

Comment: I have never heard of a guy named 'numRows', 'xmls' or 'deviceNumbers.'  Besides, you are simply not updating your dataset, which you don't know, by the way.

Comment: You have been very helpful in the past. I do appreciate that.
I do not understand your comments now.
I don't know what you mean by "a guy named numRows...", etc.

Sorry if something I've done is in violation of rules. Not intended.

Comment: Is tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:  implemented? Post the code please.

Comment: I see. I misread (and misunderstood) the post by @ElTomato. I will implement the tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: function and post the corrected code. Thank you!

Comment: Oops...  I made a typo.  Sorry about that...  which you don't know -> which you don't show

Comment: The problem with your `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` is, again, is that you are not updating your dataset in it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. The data for editable columns is being supplied by the dn and init arrays. In my `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` I am updating the edited `row:` value for those arrays. I'm guessing that's not what you mean though.